# Is Spec R compact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra

And if so, why? I'm having some trouble with this. I know that the $D_{f}$ (set of primes not containing $f$) are the open sets and form a basis for the Zariski topology; but I do not know how to go about even constructing an open cover. Thanks.

Comment: You do not _construct_ an open cover. Rather, you must show that any _given_ open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: Okay right. But what would a given open cover look like? Sorry I'm kind of a nooby in the topology area.

Comment: For $R=F[X]$ for $F$ a field the topology is just the finite complement topology, which clearly leads to a compact space.

Comment: Dear @Mike : The question I duped this against was in the Related Questions to the right, which means it probably showed up as you were typing the question statement. Please use the search features before posting a question. Regards